# Finding records with no associated records in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets

  scope :with_dog, join(:pets).where("pets.type = 'Dog'")
  scope :without_pets ???????????????????????????????????
end

class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :people
end
```

I'd like to add a scope to the Person model that returns people who have no pets.  Any ideas?  I feel like this is obvious, but it's escaping me at the moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Person.joins('left outer join pets on persons.id=pets.person_id').
       select('persons.*,pets.id').
       where('pets.id is null')
```

I haven't tested it but it ought to work.

The idea is that we're performing a left outer join, so the pets fields will be null for every person that has no pets. You'll probably need to include `:readonly => false` in the join since ActiveRecord returns read-only objects when `join()` is passed a string.

Comment: Resulting sql that fails: SELECT persons.*, pets.id FROM `persons` left outer join pets where persons.id = pets.person_id WHERE `persons`.`deleted` = 0 AND (pets.id is null)

Comment: Oops! I mistyped that join.  It should have been "...on persons.id=pets.person_id", not "...where persons.id=...".

Comment: Do you need the ",pets.id" in select('persons.*,pets.id')? It has the potential to collide with persons.id unless you alias the column like this: select('persons.*,pets.id as pet_id')

Answer (score 22):

```
scope :without_pets, lambda { includes(:pets).where('pets.id' => nil) }
```

Comment: though LEFT OUTER JOIN is not the purpose of `includes`, it with the combination of a query will result in LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: This works, regardless of purpose. Less handwritten sql than accepted answer = I think it's better.

Answer (score 5):

Mark Westling's answer is correct.  The outer join is the right way to go.  An inner join (which is what the joins method generates if you pass it the name/symbol of an association and not your own SQL) will not work, as it will not include people who do not have a pet.

Here it is written as a scope:

```
scope :without_pets, joins("left outer join pets on pets.person_id = persons.id").where("pets.id is null")
```

(If that doesn't work, try replacing 'persons' with 'people' -- I'm not sure what your table name is.)

Answer (score 1):

You must use a LEFT OUTER JOIN in order to find records without associated records. Here's an adapted version of a code I use:

```
scope :without_pets, joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN pets ON people.id = pets.person_id').group('people.id').having('count(pets.id) = 0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if your pet model has a person id, but maybe this attempt helps you somehow

```
scope :with_dog, joins(:pets).where("pets.type = 'Dog'")
scope :without_pets, joins(:pets).where("pets.person_id != persons.id")
```

Update: Corrected the query method name from 'join' to 'joins'.