# Rails 5 - Joins null association without using join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

## What do I want

What I need to get **all orders without acceptance for a given user**, but I'm having issues with the first part only.

## What do I have

Here are my models

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :acceptance
end

class Acceptance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
end
```

## What have I tried

I have already checked this answers

- [Rails 4 scope to find parents with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children/18082147#18082147)
- [Finding records with no associated records in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332093/finding-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3)

But they applied for a has_many - belongs to scenario (which is, presumably, why they fail). My scenario is simpler: **has_one - belongs_to**.

So far (after trying by myself, and reading other SO questions) the following have failed.

- `Order.includes(:acceptance).where(acceptance: { id: nil})`
- `Order.left_outer_joins(:acceptance).where(acceptance: { id: nil })`
- `Order.joins(:acceptance).merge(Acceptance.where(order_id: nil, id: nil))`

Moreover, I **can't do** `Order.joins(:acceptance)` because that immediately fetches `orders` with an `acceptance` associated, I want the opposite of that.

Didn't seem that hard a priori, but it's giving a mild pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Order.includes(:acceptance).where(acceptances: { id: nil})` should work. You have missed `s` at the end. When you construct the query using `where` statement with nested hash parameters, first key is always table name

Comment: Nevermind about last comment, just read wrong. Is there a way to **not use** table names and keep everything between models?

Comment: No, I don't think so. If you do not want to use hard coded table name, then you can use `Acceptance.table_name` instead

Comment: Ok, will have to do. Thanks!